Buildroot mandatory packages: Unable to locate package which
I want to install Buildroot on a Debian 11. When installing the mandatory packages, however, I have the problem that the package which cannot be found. How can I still install this package?
sudo apt-get install which

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package which

I have already tried to find out whether the package is installed by another package.

which is debian-specific, so it is is in debianutils which is priority: required so you should normally already have it installed: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#priorities
What kind of setup are you using where you don't have debianutils installed?

you should try "gnu-which"
